# combine Boostrap and plain HTML CSS files into wordpress theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am new to website design, sorry if this sounds like a silly question, I am working on a wordpress project where I have 4 pages in my project in total [home, about us, services and contactus]

I have built the home page and contact us page using bootstrap4 and services page using plain HTML and CSS. now i have 2 style.css sheets (style1.css and style2.css) style1 pertaining to bootstrap pages and style2 pertaining to plain HTML CSS. can i combine all these into a wordpress theme?

Answer (score 0):

## Combining External CSS files in the WordPress site

One of the easiest ways to do this is to use a free WordPress plugin called [Autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/), developed by [Frank Goossens](http://blog.futtta.be/about/).

This plugin is pretty lightweight, only 176 KB to be exact. As of writing this, it currently has over 1,000,000 active installs with a 4.7 out of 5-star rating.

```
STEP 1
```

You can download it by searching for it within your WordPress dashboard under “Add New” plugins.

```
STEP 2
```

Once installed you will want to go into the settings and enable the “Optimize CSS Code” option. This will concatenate (combine) your CSS files. And if you are using a Bootstrap CDN, make sure to input your CDN URL. This way your CSS files will load as one single request on your CDN.

[image]

```
RESULT
```

After enabling the above settings you will now see your CSS files in one “autoptimize_xxxxx.css” file.

[image]